# How to prevent my process from being killed on logout in Windows?

Tags: winapi

How can I allow my process to persist after logout and not be killed, preferably without requiring the process to have administrator privileges? I am unable to use a service/scheduled task due to some peculiarities in the program.

Comment: Did you mean on log off?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of program is this? And why do you need it to stay alive after logoff?

Comment: Make a service/scheduled task.

Comment: What peculiarities?

Comment: Write a service, or don't log out.

Comment: Processes are owned by sessions. When a user logs out, the user's session is destroyed. There are no processes in the spirit world.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to achieve this is through a Windows service. They are designed to run while the machine is on, independent of any interactive user logins.

You state in an edit that you aren't able to use a service. If that really is true then your task is not viable. My guess is that if you design your service correctly, perhaps interacting with a companion desktop app, then a service is perfectly feasible.

Comment: It doesn't have to be written as a service. The program can be run in session 0 using a scheduled task or psexec. But if the program needs UI, then it should be split into two components -- a background service and an interactive frontend.